# How to trigger Offline data collection with Smartmontools?

Tags: ssd, disk, smart

I just purchased a new SSD and I'm trying to figure out how to monitor the expected lifetime of it. When I run

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

it reports

```
...
General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) **Offline data collection activity
                    was never started**.
...
```

Furthermore I note that some of the statistics are indicated to be updated "Always" or "Offline":

```
$ sudo smartctl -data -A /dev/sda
...
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE    
...    
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   001    Old_age   **Offline**      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   001    Old_age   **Always**       -       0
202 **Perc_Rated_Life_Used**    0x0018   100   100   001    Old_age   **Offline**      -       0
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   001    Old_age   **Always**       -       0
```

Does this mean that the "Offline" stats are not up-to-date?

Will the "Offline" stats update themselves with time, or need I trigger them to update somehow?

I am particularly interested in the value indicating the lifetime of the SSD, "Perc_Rated_Life_Used", which is labeled as "Offline".

Using the `--offlineauto=on` flag (credit to Michael Krell's suggestion below) as so:

```
sudo smartctl --offlineauto=on -a /dev/sda
```

produces a new output section:

```
=== START OF ENABLE/DISABLE COMMANDS SECTION ===
SMART Automatic Offline Testing Enabled **every four hours**.
```

However, the smart data section still reports:

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                 **was never started**.
```

This is on a newly updated Ubuntu <del>13.10</del>16.04 system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/test_offline) site:

> Note that a one-time offline test can also be carried out immediately
>   upon receipt of a user command. See the `-t offline` option, which
>   causes a one-time offline test to be carried out immediately.

So, executing:

```
sudo smartctl -t offline /dev/sda
```

updates the smart data section to:

```
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                 was completed without error.
```

Problem solved.

Answer (score 7):

referring to the [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Howto_ReadSmartctlReports_ATA) site:

> **Column Updated**
>   Some SMART attributes values, that are updated only during off-line
>   data collection activities are labeled "Offline" in column "UPDATED".

How to enable "[Offline data collection](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/test_offline)":

```
smartctl --offlineauto=on
```

Comment: Thanks, this would seem like a good idea, but does not have the expected result on my system. Please see updated question above.